# Maximum and minimum of $f(x,y)=2x^3+y^4$ on $D=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2: x^2+y^2=1, x \in \left[0, \frac {1}{4} \right], y\ge 0 \}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Well, I'd tried to use the Lagrange multipliers to solve this, but I've gotten values for $x$ out of $x \in \left[0, \frac{1}{4}\right]$. Then, I've tried to parameterize $x^2+y^2=1$ with $cos^2(t)+sin^2(t)=1$:
$$\gamma(t)=(cos(t), sin(t))$$
$$f(\gamma(t))=2cos^3(t)+sin^4(t)$$
$$f'(\gamma(t))=4sin^3(t)cos(t)-6sin(t)cos^2(t)$$

I know I have to do $f'(\gamma(t))=0$ to get critical points, but I can't solve that equation yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $$4\sin^3(t)\cos(t)-6\sin(t)\cos^2(t)=2\sin(t)\cos(t)(2+\cos(t))(1-2\cos(t))\qquad\arccos\left(\tfrac14\right)\leqslant t\leqslant\tfrac\pi2$$

Answer (score 0):

You do not need Lagrange multipliers on this problem. And, as you say, the results of Lagrange lie outside the intervals restricting $x$ and $y$.

Since $y^2=1-x^2$ we can rewrite $f$ as a function of $x$ alone for $-1\le x\le1$.

\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)&=&2x^3+(1-x^2)^2\\
&=&x^4+2x^3-2x^2+1
\end{eqnarray}

So set

\begin{eqnarray}
f^\prime(x)&=&4x^3+6x^2-4x\\
&=&2x(2x^2+3x-2)\\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray}

This gives critical points at $x=-2,\,0,\,\frac{1}{2}$ but only $0,\,\frac{1}{2}$ lie in $[-1,1]$.

So $f(x)$ is increasing in the intervals $[-1,0)$ and $(\frac{1}{2},1]$ and decreasing on $(0,\frac{1}{2})$. Our concern is the interval $[0,\frac{1}{4}]$ where it is decreasing.

Thus $f(x,y)=2x^3+y^4$ has a maximum value on the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ at the point $(0,1)$ where $f(0,1)=1$ and a minimum value at the point $(\frac{1}{4},\frac{\sqrt{15}}{4})$ where $f(\frac{1}{4},\frac{\sqrt{15}}{4})=\frac{233}{256}$.

I have provided a desmos.com annimation https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2xiqbeboq5

for the level curves of $f(x,y)=2x^3+y^4$ together with the graph of $x^2+y^2=1$ restricted to $y\ge0,\,0\le x\le\frac{1}{4}$